# Can't deserialise from Json using nlohman json using custom class with private members

Tags: c++, json

Really struggling to do this; it should be really simple, but I can't work out how. I've got it working for struct, but not for a class with private members. Following instructions from (https://github.com/nlohmann/json). I'm building this on Visual Studio 2019 and obtained the library from nuget, version 3.10.4.

The error is on the get line in main.cpp, where it says "no matching overloaded function call found.". There are two other errors listed;

> Error (active)    E0304   no instance of overloaded function
> "nlohmann::basic_json<ObjectType, ArrayType, StringType, BooleanType,
> NumberIntegerType, NumberUnsignedType, NumberFloatType, AllocatorType,
> JSONSerializer, BinaryType>::get [with ObjectType=std::map,
> ArrayType=std::vector, StringType=std::string, BooleanType=bool,
> NumberIntegerType=int64_t, NumberUnsignedType=uint64_t,
> NumberFloatType=double, AllocatorType=std::allocator,
> JSONSerializer=nlohmann::adl_serializer,
> BinaryType=std::vector<uint8_t, std::allocator<uint8_t>>]" matches the
> argument
> list  Assignment4 C:\Users\allsoppj\source\repos\Assignment4\Assignment4\main.cpp 120
> object type is: json

> Error C2672   'nlohmann::basic_jsonstd::map,std::vector,std::string,bool,int64_t,uint64_t,double,std::allocator,nlohmann::adl_serializer,std::vector<uint8_t,std::allocator<uint8_t>>::get':
> no matching overloaded function
> found Assignment4 C:\Users\allsoppj\source\repos\Assignment4\Assignment4\main.cpp 120
>
> Error C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type
> nlohmann::basic_jsonstd::map,std::vector,std::string,bool,int64_t,uint64_t,double,std::allocator,nlohmann::adl_serializer,std::vector<uint8_t,std::allocator<uint8_t>>::get(void)
> noexcept()
> const'    Assignment4 C:\Users\allsoppj\source\repos\Assignment4\Assignment4\main.cpp 120

Here's my address1.h

```
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include <string>

using json = nlohmann::json;

class address1 {
private:
    std::string street;
    int housenumber;
    int postcode;

public:
    address1(std::string street, int housenumber, int postcode);
    NLOHMANN_DEFINE_TYPE_INTRUSIVE(address1, street, housenumber, postcode);
};
```

address1.cpp

```
#include "address1.h"

address1::address1(std::string street, int housenumber, int postcode) :street(street), housenumber(housenumber), postcode(postcode) {}
```

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    address1 p1 = { "home",2,3 };
    json j = p1;
    auto p3 = j.get<address1>();
    std::cout << std::setw(2) << j << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `address1` type does not have a default constructor. From https://nlohmann.github.io/json/features/arbitrary_types/#basic-usage :

> When using get<your_type>(), your_type MUST be DefaultConstructible.
> (There is a way to bypass this requirement described later.)

If I add `address1() = default;` to your example, then it compiles no problem.

Ps. The "bypass described later" can be found here: https://nlohmann.github.io/json/features/arbitrary_types/#how-can-i-use-get-for-non-default-constructiblenon-copyable-types

Comment: Thank you very much! I really can't tell you how much I needed that!